# A group with five elements is Abelian

Tags: group-theory

I tried to prove the following theorem: A group with five elements is abelian.

I know only the definition of a group and a subgroup but no more.(this is a problem from Topics in Algebra by IN Herstein). I tried a few things but to no avail.

Suppose that the group is $G=\{e,g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4\}$. $g_1g_2$ cannot be $g_1$ or $g_2$ or else one of them will be the identity,$e$.So, $g_1g_2$ is either $g_3$ or $g_4$ or $e$.

Case I: $g_1g_2=e$.(so, $g_2g_1=e$).
Then $g_1g_3=g_2$ or $g_4$($g_1g_3\not=e$,or else $g_2=g_3$). Say,$g_1g_3=g_2$. That is, $g_1=g_3^{-1}g_2\implies g_1g_2=g_3^{-1}g_2^2=e$ or in other words, $g_2^2=g_3$. Using this, $g_3g_1=g_2^2g_1=g_2(g_2g_1)=g_2$ and we have $g_1g_3=g_1g_2^2=g_2$.

Maybe, this will lead to a solution but I was wondering if there is a much smarter way to do it as this leads to a lot of casework! .

Comment: Easiest way: two facts which you may know already, if not they are quite easy to prove - try it.  (1) Any group with a prime number of elements is cyclic.  (2) Any cyclic group is abelian.

Comment: What is the order of $g_1$? what is the subgroup generated by $g_1$? it is abelian?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Proposition 1**: Any group of prime order is cyclic.

Let $G$ be a non trivial group of order $p$ and take $g\in G$, $g\neq1$. So $\langle g\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$, hence its order must divide $p$, which is prime, so $|\langle g\rangle|=p$, hence $\langle g\rangle=G$.

> **Proposition 2**: Any cyclic group is abelian.

A finite cyclic group is by definition of the type $G=\langle g\rangle:=\{1,g,g^2,\dots,g^{n-1}\}$. The fact its elements commute follows easily.

Comment: My feeling is that this is *the best* solution.

Comment: Many thanks!!! :-)

Comment: A beautiful and simple solution indeed!

Comment: But your proof implicitly uses the Lagrange's theorem (in proof of proposition1)

Comment: You haven't read the question carefully.  You only have definition of groups and subgroups at your disposal.

Comment: I'm currently grading this exact problem for an undergraduate Abstract Algebra class, where the students don't know Lagrange's theorem. The professor I'm grading for said the point of the problem is to help students appreciate theorems like Lagrange's theorem better.

Answer (score 43):

Hint: suppose your group is *not* abelian. Then you can find two *different* elements, say (after renumbering) $g_1$ and $g_2$, not equal to the identity, such that $g_1g_2 \neq g_2g_1$. Then the elements $\{e, g_1,g_2, g_1g_2, g_2g_1\}$ are *all* different. Now try to derive a contradiction (look at $g_1^2$ - which element of the set is this? Do the same for $g_1g_2g_1$).

Below are more details.

> In a finite group, there's no non-trivial element such that $g_1^2=g_1$. Also $g_1^2$ cannot be neither $g_1g_2$ nor $g_2g_1$, because $g_2\neq g_1$. Since $g_2=g_1^2$ would yield $g_1g_2=g_1^3=g_2g_1$, it's imposible, too. Therefore $g_1^2=e$. We now observe $g_1g_2g_1$. Note that $g_1,\, g_1g_2,\, g_2g_1\neq e$, with operating on both left and right, $g_1g_2g_1\neq g_1g_2,\, g_2g_1,\, g_1$. However, if $g_1g_2g_1=e$, we'll have $g_1g_2=g_1^{-1}=g_2g_1$; if $g_1g_2g_1=g_1$, $g_1g_2=e=g_2g_1$ will be produced. A contradiction is hence derived.

Comment: Anyone who knows group theory could have answered this by referring to Lagrange’s theorem. I like this answer for keeping it completely elementary

Comment: This is beautiful! Very neat trick.

Comment: Does this also use the fact that the set $\{g^n: n \in N\}$ is a subgroup of G, i.e. $g_1^2 \in G$?

Comment: It uses the fact that a group is closed under its algebraic operation, so yes.

Comment: This is the most elementary proof! I like it because it doesn't have any heavy machinery behind it.

Comment: "In a finite group, there's no element such that $g_1^2 = g_1$". Well, that's not true :-) You mean -- in a finite group, there's no non-trivial such element.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Thanks, I did not add that clarification "Below are more details", somebody else did. But I corrected it, since you are perfectly right!

Answer (score 1):

It is known that the order of a conjugacy class from a group element divides the order of the group. With $|G|=5$, this results either in one conjugacy class with $5$ elements, or five conjugacy classes with one element. Since the identity element always has its own conjugacy class, the first case is impossbible. Because all conjugacy classes have only one element, is $G$ commutative.

Comment: The fact that the size of a conjugacy class divides the order of the group is even less elementary than the fact that the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group.

Comment: You're right, but this non-elementary fact gives a short proof, which IMHO is favourable in algebra.

Comment: but clearly inappropriate for this particular question.

Comment: It is not the simplest proof, but it is an original and different one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. There is a "smarter" way to do it, but it requires more knowledge of theorems. Part of the point of this exercise is to help you appreciate those theorems more when you learn them (since you asked the question 6 years ago, I'm assuming you've learned it by now, but I'm answering in case anyone else has the same question).

My solution had three parts: First, assume $a,b\in G$ with $a\neq b$. The first part is to show that $e,a,b,ab,ba$ are all distinct (that's ${5\choose 2} = 10$ equalities you have to disprove). This lets you conclude that these five elements are exactly the five elements of $G$. Next, show that $a$ and $b$ are each their own inverses, and $(ba)^{-1}=ab$. Finally, analyze the element $aba$, and show that you get a contradiction no matter which of the five elements of $G$ is equal to $aba$.

Since it's apparently a fairly common undergraduate problem, I won't give the entire solution, but that outline should give you clear enough guidance that you can fill in the details yourself.