# Show that all groups of order $<6$ are abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

My goal is to show that groups of order < 6 are abelian in a more elegant way than just listing all possible Latin squares. To do this, my first problem where I got stuck, is how to prove that all groups of order p prime are abelian. Can someone help me?

Thanks & have a nice evening!

Comment: Hint: all groups of order $p$ are in fact cyclic. Proving this might be a bit easier for you.

Comment: I think that you could try a google search yourself. Certainly a minimum of group theory is useful, in particular Lagrange's theorem. The next goal then for you could be to show that groups of order $p^2$ are abelian. Of course, you can find the solution by googling, too.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know Lagrange, so that's a nice hint :-)

Comment: Edited to make title consistent with subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For small groups follow the strategy that is laid out here and complies with the very basic axioms of a group: [A group with five elements is Abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909733/a-group-with-five-elements-is-abelian).
(Scroll a bit down to see my solution, that also works for groups of order 2, 3 and 4.) You will not need the fact that groups of prime order are cyclic (hence abelian).

Comment: Thanks very much - that's it, nice way for proofing this. For order 2, 3 and 4 it's even easier: just suppose that ab nonequal ba for some elements a and b not the identity element and hence we have already 5 different elements in the group.

Comment: You are welcome! If you deem my answer being the right one, please tick it as such, being a habit at this Math StackExchange community. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The proof of this is literally anywhere with just a Google search. It follows from Lagrange's theorem: any non-identity element $x$ generates a subgroup, which has order either $1$ or $p$; but it cannot be $1$ since $x$ is not the identity element. Can you finish it from here?

Answer (score -1):

You do not even need to go there.

Another way to prove it is that a finite ordered non-abelian group must have order 6 or greater which can be done like this

if $|G|=1$ then it's trivial, So assume $|G|>1$ then there exist $a\in G$, but all groups have inverses so $a^{-1}\in G$, which means $|G|\geq 3$, but this case would be abelian so there must be another element $b\in G$ and equally so it's inverse, so we have that $|G|\geq 5$, But we also have that $ab\in G$, which would give one of the following $ab=a$, $ab=b$, $ab=e$, $ab=a^{-1}$ or $ab=b^{-1}$, the first ones can be eliminated as they imply that either $a$ or $b$ are identity or inverse, the latter two can be eliminated for the reason that they would make it abelian as we get $aba=a^2b=e$, with left and right a multiplication on $ab=a^{-1}$. This gives us that $ab=ba$ for the elements which clearly doesn't work as it is a non-abelian group and the remainder would be the same (with the inverses etc), so there must exist some other element then. So $|G|\geq 6$

Comment: I think that doesn't work, however thanks for the idea of this way, but I think it omits the possibility that in a non-abelian group, only one element has to be different from its inverse, for the others it may be the same. So your way doesn't work like that for order 4, I think.

Comment: It works all the way

Comment: So, why do we have order > 4? the inverse of the additional element b could be itself, so we have only 4 elements, not as you stated at least 5; or is there a fault in thinking this way?

Comment: Because then it is abelian, let $e,a,a^{-1},b$ be our group, then we have $e$ commute with all, $a,a^{-1}$ with each other and $b$ with itself, we also have $ab$ must be in it, but it can only be one of the 4 elements, and all possibilities can be seen resulting in either being the inverse or commuting.

Comment: In short, the alternatives are either than all elements are not unique or it is abelian

Comment: Ok, now I understand it, thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome, considerbaccepting it then